# RoR Rake Task: How to run a command after server foreground

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, rake-task

So basically I am trying to create a rake task that starts up a server. Then I want to open up a browser to hit the url to access that server. Right now I am running into an issue where I can't open up the browser. I believe the reason is because the server starts on the foreground and once something is in the foreground, I can't actually run another command.

I can run it into the background and I believe that would solve my issue. However, that would mean I would have to manually look for the process afterwards and kill it. I would prefer to just ctrl+C when I am done with that server.

The other solution is to open up the browser manually which isn't too bad, but I rather prefer not to. I have something like this so far in my rake tasks.

```
    task :unit_tests do
      sh('run some tests')
      sh('run some server')
      sh('open up some browser')
    end
```

Comment: have you considered using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) ?

Comment: I thought that only work on unit tests. Also I think it only works when a server is already running. While I am actually running a server, I am doing it via the script, which means on the same tab, I am running a server on the foreground. So I can't run another command right?